Generic types dependencies between function arguments
I'm trying to use binding for a game engine. And I want to add a little typing
/** Engine external functions  */
export type Message<TBody> = { }

// This function returns same unique object for same `s`
// This is internal engine object. Only for comparison from user code
declare function Message<TBody>(s: string): Message<TBody>;

declare function sendMessage<B>(message: Message<B>, body: B): void;

/** User code */

// User create messages at start
const MessageMove: Message<{x: number, y: number}> = Message("move");
const MessageHit: Message<{damage: number}> = Message("hit");

// sendMessage resolve types right
sendMessage(MessageMove, {});
sendMessage(MessageHit, { damage: 100 });

// I need write a lot of implementations of the `recieveMessage` function
// But I have not idea how to make body type depend from message without bolertplait code
class MyActor {
    recieveMessage<B>(message: Message<B>, body: B) {
        if (message === MessageMove) {
            //type of body is `B` but I waiting for `{ x: number, y: number }`
            console.log(body.x, body.y);        
        } else if (message === MessageHit) {
            //also `B`
            console.log(body.damage);
        }
    }
}

I can change types declration. But message and body must always be splitted
I try same tricks I now but not results.
The only way I found out is to make huge function declarations every time
recieveMessage(message: "a"|"b"|"c", body: message extends "a" ? ... : message extends "b" ...

or long overloads for function.

One approach is to use the TypeScript discriminated union type.
The sample code is here:
enum MessageType {
    A,
    B,
}
type MessageMove = {
    type: MessageType.A,
    body: {x: number, y: number}
}

type MessageHit = {
    type : MessageType.B,
    body: {damage: number}
}
type MessageAction = MessageMove | MessageHit;

declare function sendMessage(message: MessageAction): void;

class MyActor {
    recieveMessage(message: MessageAction) {
        switch(message.type) {
            case MessageType.A:
                console.log(message.body.x, message.body.y);
                break;
            case MessageType.B:
                console.log(message.body.damage);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('inavalid type')
        }
       
    }
}

for more reading, refer to https://medium.com/gitconnected/type-first-code-later-6c0dfd449035



I can change types declration. But message and body must always be splitted



added a new answer to have keep them splitted.

To keep the message and body splitted, we need to have a "lookup" from the body by a key in the message.
type TBody = 'A' | 'B';

type Message<TBody> = { 
    name: TBody
}
type DataSchema = {
  A:
  {
    body:{
      x: number, y: number
  }
  },
  B: {
    body:{
      damage: number
  }
  },
}
type PropertyType<T, Path extends string> = Path extends keyof T ? T[Path] : never;
type lookup<T, Key extends keyof T, prop extends string> = PropertyType<T[Key], prop>;

Then the receiveMessage can be written as:
recieveMessage<TBody extends keyof DataSchema>(message: Message<TBody>, body: lookup<DataSchema, TBody, 'body'>) {


Hm. I thik I checked something like this. Body resolved as { x: number; y: number; } | { damage: number; }  insede if (body.name === 'A')

I feel that I need resolve TBody as literal with infer something like: recieveMessage(message: Message<infer M>: body: Body<M>)   but it seems I still not understand how infer works.

@Onni The lookup ensure, the calling of the receiveMessage can differential the message and body. i.e. if you call recieveMessage<'A'>({name:'A'}, {damage: 'a'}), the compiler will error out. As for inside the method, you need to implement a type guard, for example, if('x'in body) {console.log(body.x);}

It is not comfortable. I like behavior like discriminated union. Thank you. Sorry I can't rating you

I think. may be use type guards
function MessageHit(m: unknown, body: unknown): body is { damage: number } { return m === "hit" }
